# Git Folder Path spelling Capitalization mismatch

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tortoisegit

I am new in git.
I am playing Tortoise git client on windows and it show path as small letter while it is in Capital letter for folder path.
Screenshot is as below.

[image]

as you can see path real path on Windows Iis as `E:\HRIS\HRIS_Leave\Application\HRIS 3.5\SageFrame\Modules\HRISLeave\js` but it must need to be shown as

```
Application/HRIS 3.5/SageFrame/Modules/HRISLeave/js
```

but it shows as

```
application/hris 3.5/sageframe/Modules/HRISLeave/js
```

i have other files on this directory too but they shown in path

```
Application/HRIS 3.5/SageFrame/Modules/HRISLeave/js
```

only LeaveRequest.js is on another folder on git but in disk it located on same folder.
how to resolve this issue or move this file to exact folder path.

Answer (score 0):

See [TortoiseGit issue #2559](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2559)
and [issue #1268](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/1268)

Could be a **workaround**: Do not set the Cache of Icon Overlay to *Default*, use the others.

---

Those issues are closed at Aug 18, 2015.